# Python list append and extend gives me a NONE. I want them to be an appended and extended list each. What is the reason?

Tags: python, list

I want to know why this code is giving me a NONE.

```
def main():

    x = ['a','b','c','d','e']
    y = ['v','w','x','y','z']
    z1 = x.append(y)
    z2 = x.extend(y)
    print z1
    print z2

main()
```

Comment: They both return `None`...

Comment: @blue_mango just put x+y instead x.append(y)

Comment: @hisi Thanks. But I guess that is a substitution for extend instead of append. I still wonder why the code returns a NONE.

Comment: list.append(x) add an item to the end of the list and return None.

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer that I wanted:)